# Delay before showing the tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, simpletip

I use simpletip jquery plugin and I want to make some changes in it. I want the tooltip to appear after some time (milliseconds) when hovering the link. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with jquery enough. Can anyone point out how this can be done?

http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can define a custom effect for showing the tooltip.

In your configuration, define showEffect: 'custom', and showCustom property.  It should look something like this:

```
showEffect: 'custom',
showCustom: function(tip, duration) {
    tip.delay(550).fadeIn(duration);
}
```

In this case, the fadeIn will be delayed for 550 milliseconds.  duration is the showTime specified in your configuration, or, if omitted 150 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the onBeforeShow callback event in the simpletip plugin, and just use a delay in that so it delays before it returns and continues to show the tip.