# jQuery simpletip and hoverIntent (delay before showing the tooltip)

Tags: jquery, hoverintent, simpletip

I have the same question like this:

[Delay before showing the tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797769/delay-before-showing-the-tooltip)

I need a delay before showing the tooltip.

So i want to use the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.

I don't understand how to combine the two plugins.

```
$("#demo2 li").hoverIntent( makeTall, makeShort )
```

and

```
$("#demo2 li").simpletip()
```

together

```
$("#demo2 li").hoverIntent(
       $("#demo2 li").simpletip("show"),
       $("#demo2 li").simpletip("hide")
)
```

does not work for me.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var timeout = null;
$("#demo2 li").onmouseenter(function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
          $(this).fadeTo(1, "slow"); // or any other action
         }, 300);
})
.onmouseleave(function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
          $(this).fadeTo(0.3, "fast"); // or any other action
        }, 300);
});
```

Maybe a plugin for a calendar, or a nice dialog. But not for a delay on hovers.